# Get text of textView from another activity

Tags: java, android, android-intent, static, textview

I am trying to get text from textview which is located in class 2 to use it in class 1 by pressing a button. I do this by sending an Intent, but i got the error of my content. That is what i am trying to send (from class 2 to class 1):

```
public static void intent_send(){
Intent i = new Intent();
i.putExtra("number",Integer.parseInt(text_view_current_page.getText().toString()));
class2.startActivity(i);
}
```

text_view_current_page is a static TextView, otherwise it has an error in this void. I call this void by pressing a button in class 1:

```
Class2.intent_send();
Intent i = getIntent();
Bundle b = i.getExtras();
PagerNumber = b.getInt("number");
```

I have an error in the line of the content definition:

```
i.putExtra("number",Integer.parseInt(text_view_current_page.getText().toString()));
```

What should i do with this textView to be able get it's text from another class by pressing a button? Should it be static or should i declare it in that class which receives an intent?

Comment: What is the error you are getting? context of static depends on your code. because intent_send is static so you need a static variable.!

Comment: The simulation stops at line of "i.putExtra" and gives me the following description of the error:  threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x417daae0)  and  of course  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: check the textview whether you have initialized  in you ractivity before getting the text. text_view_current_page.getText() . For more info you need to paste the code!

Answer (score 1):

In Android activities are *fully* separated components and hence those cannot access each other's stuff directly. Those have their own window and view hierarchy which are private only to the owner activity itself.

Nevertheless there are a couple of ways for activities to interact with each other.

1. Sending data when you are starting second activity via Intent.
2. Utilizing Application object as a share object among all app's components.
3. Registering in-activity broadcast receivers by which you can send signals between activities.

**My Recommendation for your case:**

If in your case, the second activity should have a very close relation with the first one (e.g. accessing its view hierarchy), you could implement the second activity as a dialog or fragment not an activity.